# CSS APDIV moving when browser is resized and not being placed where needed

Tags: css, html, position

Hey all i have a wonderful CSS problem here.

I am trying to use an APDIV that has a style of:

```
#name {
    position: absolute;
    width: 356px;
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 43px;
    top: 1000px;
}

#donation_form {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:785px;
    height:520px;
    background-image:url(../img/formBG_ChattClub.gif);
}
```

And that looks great in dreamweaver in design view:
[image: dreamweaver]

**BUT** when i go to view it in the browser it shows like so:
[image: in broswer]

The HTML code for the name is:

[image: code]

**donation_container** does not have a style associated with it.

What am i missing so that it lines up with the boxes just fine without any problem??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#donation_form {
    position: relative;
}
#name {
    top: 3px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Beside what you have written already